# Show a series of slides only once

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a PowerPoint "game" for my classroom.  One slide is the "game board".  I need to transition from it, to Question 1, return to the gameboard*, then transition to Question 2, etc.

*Returning to the gameboard is currently done via a "return to slide X" action button.

I failed to find anything in searching (perhaps because I have no idea how to succinctly describe this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution over at the the [VBAExpress forums](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?48469-Macro-to-advance-to-next-slide-on-next-use-advance-to-quot-next-slide-1-quot)

```
Sub onwards() 
Static lngNum As Long 
lngNum = lngNum + 1 
With SlideShowWindows(1).View 
    .GotoSlide (.CurrentShowPosition + lngNum) 
End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of producing games w/o involving VBA.

A few people I know and trust have sites that might help:

http://powerpointmagician.com/downloads.htm

http://www.loyola.edu/edudept/PowerfulPowerPoint/

A simple action setting can return you to the previously viewed slide; that might be all you need.